# How to convert a date created from timestamp in yyyy-MM-dd format

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime

Suppose to have a date:

```
 var date_not_formatted=new Date(timestamp);
        var dateFormatted=new Date(date_not_formatted.getFullYear()+"-"+(date_not_formatted.getMonth()+1)+"-"+date_not_formatted.getDate());
```

I put this data in a input type date and I read in the console this warning:

```
The specified value "Sat Sep 15 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (daylight savings time
 dell\u2019central Europe)" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: `Date.toString()` does not return date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. You have to not cast `dateFormatted` as date and ensure that month and day has 2 digits.

Comment: Looking at your error, your timestamp format looks like the default output of the javascript console. This is really not a good place to be starting from (It's the timezone description at the end that breaks it). Serialized timestamps should be in some kind of standard, machine readable format: ISO, ticks since the epoch, etc. (The Date constructor can swallow all these happily! yyyy-MM-dd is not absolutely required.) Can you tell us what is your starting format, and perhaps why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to convert a Date to yyyy-MM-dd, you can do by this:

```js
var timestamp = 1537345115000;
var date_not_formatted = new Date(timestamp);

var formatted_string = date_not_formatted.getFullYear() + "-";

if (date_not_formatted.getMonth() < 9) {
  formatted_string += "0";
}
formatted_string += (date_not_formatted.getMonth() + 1);
formatted_string += "-";

if(date_not_formatted.getDate() < 10) {
  formatted_string += "0";
}
formatted_string += date_not_formatted.getDate();

console.log(formatted_string);
```

Note: `getMonth()` will return a zero-based value.

Comment: when I put this date to my input type date I obtain the same warning

Comment: Because the date format has to be in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. For example, `2018-09-19`, not `2018-9-19`

Comment: Should ```if (date_not_formatted.getMonth() < 9)``` not be ```if (date_not_formatted.getMonth() < 10)```?
If im wrong please could you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var timestamp = 1537345115000;
var date = new Date(timestamp);
var dd_mm_yyyy = date.toLocaleDateString();
var yyyy_mm_dd = dd_mm_yyyy.replace(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/g, "$3-$2-$1");
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help your needs accurately.But there a few many variables used just for better understanding purpose.

```
//req_date is having the date in the required format
var dat = new Date();
var req_date = dat.getFullYear().toString()+'-';
var mon = (dat.getMonth()+1).toString();
if(mon.length == 1){
    req_date += '0'+mon+'-';
}
else{
    req_date += mon+'-'
}
var da = (dat.getDate()).toString();
if(da.length == 1){
    req_date += '0'+da;
}
else{
    req_date += da
}
//console.log(req_date)//Your try checking it in browser(Output:-2018-09-19).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getFormattedDate(date) {

  const year  = date.getFullYear(),
        month = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        day   = date.getDate()

  return [year, month, day].join('-')
}
```

> Can be a one liner too, but I have broken it down for more clarity.